# Should I add insulation to basement ceiling?

Tags: insulation, basement

Currently doing a reno on our basement.  After roughing everything out, I have insulated the outside walls with R13 (2x4).  The house has never had insulation in the basement.  Should I insulate the ceiling as well?   The ceiling is 2x6 and I think R19/R22 should do.  Is this practical/good benefit or am I just wasting my time/money.  The house is in New England, basement is dry, standard poured cement style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this question will help: [How should I insulate my basement?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/3664/157)

Short answer: You don't need to insulate the ceiling, but you can optionally do it if you want some sound blocking.

Comment: Would you recommend faced or unfaced batts?  I have one room which will be the kids playroom.   The less noise the better.  Or maybe that question is a follow up.  Thx for your answer.

Comment: Use either. Foil faced is easier to secure between the floor joiosts. The humidity levels should not be a factor from your description, so condensation should not be a problem. What are you using for a source of heat in your rec room? If you say ventless natural gas or propane, we have an moisture issue now.

Comment: Heat is hot water running through baseboard copper pipes.

Comment: Fiberglass insulation will help, but what will likely be a better sound blocker is to ensure the room's ceiling is completely sealed of holes and that the ceiling's sheetrock is hung using resilient channels.